# Why do I need "java:/" prefix for @Resource injection in Wildfly 12?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, resources, wildfly

Starting with a running EAR on Weblogic 12 I need to get this app working with Wildfly 12, too.

We've got some JMS queues which we inject like this on Weblogic:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jms/Queues/MYQUEUE")
private Queue destination;

@Resource(lookup = "jms/QueueConnectionFactories/MYQUEUECF")
private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

With Wildfly I defined the queue in standalone-full.xml

```
<jms-queue name="MYQUEUE" entries="jms/Queues/MYQUEUE" durable="true"/>
<connection-factory name="MYQUEUECF" entries="jms/QueueConnectionFactories/MYQUEUECF" connectors="in-vm"/>
```

But injection fails on server startup.

```
service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.XXX.ejb.JMSMessageProducer.env.jms.Queues.MYQUEUE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.XXX.ejb.JMSMessageProducer.env."com.xxx.webservices.components.communication.ejb.JMSMessageProducerBean".destination] [[...]
```

To fix this, I need to use

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/Queues/MYQUEUE")
private Queue destination;
```

Without the "java:/" prefix, injection won't work.

Unfortunately this does not work with Weblogic (which is the leading/productive system).

Since I cannot change the weblogic configuration I have to make my Wildfly config compatible with it or change injection code so it works on both app servers.

Why does Wildfly need this prefix in the @Resource annotation to get the injection right?

Is there a way to change its config so the code works without the "java:/" prefix?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Mark.

PS: When I remove the @Resource annotations and do a context lookup, it succeeds without the "java:/" - strange ;-)

Comment: Nice question... But do you test on Wildfly and then deploy to Weblogic?

Comment: Ah, you think our dev env is Wildfly and prod is Weblogic? No - we are evaluating Wildfly as an alternative target and for now the existing codebase should work on both app servers. Later we will have two producive environments - the old with Weblogic, the other with Wildfly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following reference:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261022

I am going to quote the snippet if found in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
  <resource-ref>  
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/fs</res-ref-name>  
    <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/FS</jndi-name>  
  </resource-ref>  
</jboss-web>
```

With the deployment descriptor above, you have the ability to say that a certain resource name maps to whatever jndi name you like.
So with this you can get away with using resource annotation injection with the names that work in weblogic and mapped them to tje wildfly jndi names that need the java://

code.